# Grails: Get calling file's name in custom taglib code

Tags: grails, filenames, taglib, custom-tag

I'm writing a custom tag library and I was wondering if it's possible to get the filename of the file that invoked the custom tag?  I need that tag to behave differently depending on which file calls it and if I can get the name that would be the best approach.  Otherwise I'll just have to pass it parameters to tell it how to behave.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the controller and action name from the parameters.

```
${params.action} 
${params.controller}
```

or even

```
${actionName}
${controllerName}
```

Not sure if this is going to help, but there is also requested URI.

```
${request.forwardURI}
```

Finally, from the calling GSP for the actual filename (with path) you can use:

```
${this.getGroovyPageFileName()}
```

Comment: `$actionName` and `$controllerName` can also be used if preferred over referring to `params`.

Comment: Thanks, added that in there as well.

Comment: What is `this` in `${this.getGroovyPageFileName()}` when used inside a taglib?

Comment: Sorry, that should only be used from the calling GSP and not inside a taglib since it makes use of the GroovyPage http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/GroovyPage.html

Comment: Didn't mean to poke you on this answer. Just trying to make sure I did not get the question incorrect. Thanks for tolerating. :)

Comment: No worries. Thank you for the help and improving the Answer! Much respect.